# How to prevent multiple sound calls in update loop of game engine?

Tags: c++, logic, game-engine

I'm working on a game engine project (for learning purposes) and I've run into an issue with my audio system. I currently have a static PlaySound() function within my AudioSystem class that's defined like so:

```
void AudioSystem::PlaySound(uint16 soundID)
    {
       pendingSoundRequests[numSoundsPending].id = soundID;
       numSoundsPending++;
    }
```

Keeping in mind things are simplified here for ease of understanding. PendingSoundRequests is an array of soundEffect objects which only contain an id which is tied to a certain sound file. This function is called from other systems like my input system that plays a sound upon a certain key press:

```
void UpdateInput()
    {
        //....other code

       if (keypress == spaceBar)
          PlaySound(1)
    }
```

This stores a soundID of 1 which plays a certain audio file. The AudioSystem will then loop over and play all sounds in it's update loop like so:

```
void AudioSystem::Update()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < numSoundsPending; i++)
        {
            StartAudio(pendingSoundRequests[i].id);

            //Reset all sounds id's to 0 meaning no sound should be played
            //unless id is passed another number through PlaySound function
            pendingSoundRequests[i].id = 0;
        }

        numSoundsPending = 0;
}
```

This works fine if the spacebar key is pressed only once, but if I hold down the key then since the update loop is called every frame, each individual sound keeps restarting itself and only playing the first millisecond of it's sound before being cut off by the same sound having to be played again on the next loop.

How would I go about creating some logic to prevent sounds from playing multiple times when I only want them to play once on the first press of the key?

Comment: What does `StartAudio` do?

Comment: Just an example function that suppose to represent actually playing the audio.

Comment: Problem is not in AudioSystem class, it is in your input handling. You should handle single key press as a single event.

Comment: But _how_ does it play a sound?  If your API call can only handle one sound at a time that's one problem, but if it can play multiples that's a different type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a sleep after the sound is played as long as the sound takes to play which would make it not play the next sound until after one sound is played. Are you using a separate thread for your audio system?

```
void AudioSystem::Update()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < numSoundsPending; i++)
        {
            StartAudio(pendingSoundRequests[i].id);

            //sleep here as long as the sound takes

            //Reset all sounds id's to 0 meaning no sound should be played
            //unless id is passed another number through PlaySound function
            pendingSoundRequests[i].id = 0;
        }

        numSoundsPending = 0;
}
```

That might make a queue of sounds. 
So you could do something like this:

```
//get current number of sounds pending
x = numSoundsPending

//sleep

//get new current after sleep
y = numSoundsPending

//get difference
z = y - x

//skip the difference
i = i + z
```

Comment: I'm currently just doing a single threaded game engine project since it's my first game engine and things are complicated enough lol.

Comment: @Jason You should probably learn threading otherwise you wont be able to get input while your sound is playing. One thread means your sound will have to play and then return back to the input part. You should have one loop checking input and then making calls to a thread that can play sounds.

Comment: @aowen this is simply not true you can play sound on single thread as sound library can do it for you. Also waiting in game engine is not good idea you should process single frame as soon as posible.

Comment: @Logman I didn't think about using a sound library I thought he was playing the sound from the program itself.

Comment: @aowen there are multiple approach for this situation but if you are building your own sound system one of the simplest approaches is to just push for ex. 0.5s sounds to your sound card. And in every frame if needed you just push next 0.5s of sound. Sound card can buffered sounds that need to be played and there is no need to create separate thread to send every sound sample separately.

Comment: @Logman all sound libraries, and sound systems that exist in  widely used platforms, let limit us  with Linux (which got 3 different systems), WIndows APi, MacOS, wrapper libraries do that in threads. In case of windows, on API level it happens in separate process even. So.. that's not true. Sound playback is an intensive, CPU-related task, there is no "sound processor" on average PC to handle it instead.

Comment: @Swift as I point in my first comment sound library can do most work for you. But if you want to build your own library to communicate directly with your sound device this is one of the simples approaches. And to be honest there is sound controller in most PC-s that can process data and change them to analog waves but if you refers to sound data as sound files I can agree with you. To play sound file you need first decode them to valid sound format like PCM then you send those data to your sound device. But if you decode your file before playing it CPU is hardly involve in the process.

Comment: @Logman The wave-generators  are practically in past now, if you refer to those. Tis done by driver, while there are codecs DRM controls now.  Opening files and playing them back\pushing in hardware's buffers in _same_ thread where you manage input and render isn't good solution as ell. Normal approach is to keep input and rendering in same thread, physics, resource access, sound playback - in separate threads, to avoid FPS being locked to hardware interrupts, to system wait states or to complex calculations done in physics. It's prudent to have input in separate thread sometimes

Comment: @Swift what do you mean by normal approach. Normal approach for engines like unreal engine? Then yes and it even more sophisticated as they can calculate refraction echoes etc. But for "learning purposes" normal approach is to do things simple and omit thread synchronization between physic, sound, graphic, input etc. One thread is sufficient to do a simple game engine for simple game. I had the pleasure to actually build a commercial game engine and you need a bunch of people, money and time to do a good product and I don't think OP want to spend rest of his life on this project.

Comment: @ Logman sadly, main technical issues with  engines lie  exactly in synchronization. Imo, programmer should learn theory behind that way before they even try to do anything complex. Sadly, I saw example what harm does opposite approach, including developer hell in result. Yes, simple game that doesn't  push anywhere close to  potential limits of hardware can work in one thread.  Problem  with anything less than simple arcade game would be that you instantly  link _everything_ together with render process. If  rendering is slow, input is sluggish, you can't pace processes right way, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of what is currently playing, and remove it when it is done.  When you go to start a sound you should check to see if the sound is already playing.  If it is don't start the sound again.  That way you avoid the issue.

Comment: Well the question is how would I know when a sound is done playing?

Comment: @Jason as we do not know what kind of sound library you are using and I do not think you are communicate directly with your sound driver (on what os? etc.) there is no way to say how to check when sound is playing. You need to check documentation of sound library you are using to get that.

Comment: Okay. I'll see what I can find. I'll be using the SDL_Mixer audio library which works on top of SDL

Comment: @Jason but have in mind that the issue is not in your audio class but in your input handling. To picture the problem just change subject a little bit. Try to do light switch that have two states on and off and one method switch. Now using your input update method try to switch light once per spacebar press. You simple can't do thins because you will switch light every frame and not only onece per key press.

Comment: Ya I see what your saying. Thanks for the input (no pun intended).

Comment: @Jason Assuming you are playing one sound on one channel then Mix_Playing(int channel) will tell you if the sound is playing or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are three types of key event:

- Keydown: returns true only once per key press.
- Keyup: returns true only once per key press.
- Keypress: remains true when key is pressed.

you need `Keydown` event here.